# iPhone 8 randomly resumes playing podcasts and music when I plug in my headphones. Any way to stop?

Tags: iphone, audio, podcasts

I listen to music at my desk and when I get up to do something and return and plugin my headphones the music or podcast *sometimes* resumes.

Thing is, whatever app resumes playing isn't necessarily what I was listening to before. It could be a podcast, Spotify or the Music app. It's also isn't consistent and is an unpleasant surprise, particularly if the volume is up.

How do I stop this from happening?